# How do I print a variable within a class' if statement?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print a variable in Python using the following code:

```
from time import sleep
import random

class Hero:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

        if name == "rock":
            self.health = 50
            self.attack = 10

        elif name == "paper":
            self.health = 70
            self.attack = 7

        elif name == "scissors":
            self.health = 100
            self.attack = 5

    def dmg(self, other):
        other.ehealth -= self.attack

start = 1

while start == 1:
    name = input("Pick a class [rock/paper/scissors]")

    if name != "rock" or "paper" or "scissors":
        print ("That player does not exist. Try again.")
        start = 1

    else:
        start = 1

    player = Hero(name)
    enemyName = ["erock", "epaper", "escissors"]
    ename = random.choice(enemyName)

    print ("Your character is", name, "which comes with", self.health, "health, and", self.attack, "attack.")
    print("")

    sleep(1)

    print ("Your enemy is", ename, "which comes with", ehealth, "health, and", eattack, "attack.")
```

I can't figure out a way to access and print the variable "self.health" under the "Hero" class. I can access "name" just fine. Maybe it's the fact that it's under an if statement? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your code? It's difficult to tell what your code looks like in the current format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is just a parameter name used inside the methods. Don't use it outside the method.

To access the variables refer to them using the object name (`player`) like this

```
player.health
```

The `name` variable you are printing "works" because it's not from the object. You should use the same notation to access that too:

```
player.name
```